# Почему у меня не срабатывает метод join() в потоке?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Мне нужно вычислить сложное математическое выражение, поэтому я сделал его декомпозицию, чтобы разбить его вычисление на разные потоки. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть поток №1 и поток №3. В потоке №1 я вычисляю `y1 = A*b`, а в потоке №3 я вычисляю `Y3 = A2C2-B2A2`. После этого я хочу передать `Y3` в поток №1 для вычисления `Y3y1`. Для того, чтобы подождать пока завершится поток №3, я в первом потоке вызвал метод `thread3.join();`, но он у меня почему-то не работает и в итоге во время вычисления `Y3y1` выскакивает `NullPointerException`. Если же я просто усыплю поток №1 на несколько секунд до передачи `Y3` в него, то все работает нормально. Так почему же у меня не работает метод join? И можете дать рекомендации по решению задачи и написания кода к ней?

Вот часть моего кода

```
        thread1 = new Thread(
                new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        b = calc_b();
                        matrixA = generateMatrixA(matrixOrder);
                        y1 = calc_y1(matrixA, matrixOrder);

                        // Не работает!
                        try {
                            thread3.join();
                        } catch (Exception e) {

                        }

                        // Если сделаю так, то работает.
                        // try {
                        //     thread1.sleep(4000);
                        // } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        //     e.printStackTrace();
                        // }

                        Y3new = Y3;
                        calc_Y3y1(Y3new, y1, matrixOrder);
                    }
                }
        );


                    thread3 = new Thread(
                        new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                     matrixA2 = generateMatrixA2(matrixOrder);
                     matrixB2 = generateMatrixB2(matrixOrder);
                     matrixC = generateMatrixC(matrixOrder);
                     Y3 = calc_Y3(matrixA2, matrixB2, matrixC, matrixOrder);
                            }
                        }
                );

        thread1.start();
        thread3.start();
```

Comment: thread3-то вообще существует на момент вызова `.join()`?

Comment: Зря вы подавляете исключение. Из-за этого и ваша проблема: вы просто выбрасываете сообщение об ошибке. Просто не делайте так.

Comment: @Etki я добавил кусок кода, который проглядел. Ну по логике поток №3 должен быть запущен ведь...

Comment: @VladD ну без try-catch join не хочет работать. Я проверил логами, там исключение не выбрасывает, значит join по факту исполняется. Тогда в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Ну так вы должны исправить ошибку, а не подавить её. Если не работает без try/catch, это не значит, что «так надо», это значит, что у вас баг и его нужно исправить.

Comment: Там `try-catch` необходим, т.к. `join` может выбросить `InterruptedException`, что, конечно, не оправдывает перехват всех исключений и отсутствие логирования. Плюс нужно поменять местами старты потоков, чтобы гарантировать, что к моменту `thread3.join()` поток будет запущен (при незапущеном потоке join выйдет сразу). Но да, как в ответе @Etki, вам нужно ждать не потоки, а данные. Чтобы привести пример кода через `CompletableFuture` вашего кода слишком мало...

Comment: @zRrr: Я не против try/catch, я против подавления ошибки. Точнее, вообще всех ошибок.

Comment: @zRrr спасибо, перестановка стартов потоков мне помогла и ошибка не возникает. Я даже смог разбить по потокам остальные блоки и вроде как выводит правильный результат.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Дальнейшее, конечно, не является полноценным ответом, но не могу не высказаться.

Это многопоточное программирование. В нем на произвольной строчке кода хранится десяток возможностей прострелить себе ногу, тут **нет** места "должен быть запущен". Никто не гарантирует, когда потоки стартуют, когда финишируют, какой-то может финишировать на несколько часов раньше, потому что у него взлетело исключение и прервало все на свете. Для того и существуют join'ы и всякие happens-before, чтобы в условно-неупорядоченное можно было принести ровно столько порядка, сколько требуется. И, кстати, thread3 не обязательно *запущен* в этот момент, потому что запускается он уже после запуска thread1, и thread1 имеет право хоть целиком финишировать к моменту запуска thread3 - я все равно не понимаю, откуда там NPE, но на энном запуске вполне вероятно, что вы столкнулись бы именно с той проблемой, что thread3 в тот момент еще не запущен.

Что касательно общей архитектуры, то она правильна по идее, но не очень хороша по реализации. Различные ветви выполнения действительно должны ждать результатов выполнения друг от друга, но они вместо результатов ждут потоки. Вместо этого стоило бы создать как минимум объекты-обертки результатов с примитивным интерфейсом на wait/notify (к своему стыду, я до сих пор в нем не разобрался, и не могу сказать подробнее), а как максимум - обернуть все в `CompletableFuture` или аналог, который полностью снимает головную боль по управлению тредами и предоставляет возможность удобно работать с асинхронными вычислениями.

Пример, как это могло бы работать на CompletableFuture:

```
CompletableFuture<Integer> y3 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(calculator::calcY3);
CompletableFuture<Integer> y1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(calculator::calcY1);

// выполнится только тогда, когда оба предыдущих CompletableFuture предоставят результат
CompletableFuture<Integer> ySum = y3.thenCombine(y1, (y3, y1) -> y3 + y1);

System.out.println(ySum.get());
```

[Хорошее введение в CompletableFuture от Томаша с непроизносимой фамилией](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2013/05/java-8-definitive-guide-to.html). Отдельно отмечу момент, что если не указывать executor, то CompletableFuture будут использовать `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()`, что вряд ли является желаемым поведением (и, насколько понимаю, `.parallelStream()` из Stream API использует его же).

CompletableFuture появились в Java 8, но паттерн (по понятным причинам) весьма распространенный, поэтому аналоги давно существуют в third-party библиотеках (ListenableFuture в guava, например). И, понятное дело, в Java < 8 нет лямбд, поэтому надо будет полноценно реализовывать анонимные классы.

Comment: То есть join мог сработать даже, если thread3 не был запущен? NPE срабатывает потому, что когда я уже пытаюсь вычислить Y3y1 у меня в Y3 null, а не числа (это матрица) - значит эти числа не передались из thread3 в thread1. Если просто усыпить thread1 на пару секунд, то все нормально передается. Как же мне тогда правильно в thread1 подождать пока выполнится thread3? Я думал, что если я буду использовать thread3.join(), то thread1 сделает паузу пока Y3 не будет вычислен и в результате я смогу использовать Y3 в первом потоке.

Comment: *То есть join мог сработать даже, если thread3 не был запущен?* - да, взгляните [в исходники](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Thread.java.html#1241). Все висит на `isAlive()`, цитирую докблок: *A thread is alive if it has been started and has not yet died.*

Comment: @Kostya *Как же мне тогда правильно в thread1 подождать пока выполнится thread3?* - я об этом написал, вам нужно ждать не тред, а результат, методов для этого куча - хоть от костылей на основе очереди до того самого интерфейса wait-notify и очень удобных CompletableFuture.

Comment: @Etki: Судя по всему, _Нуркевич_?

Comment: @VladD по-прежнему боюсь даже пробовать произнести

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и объяснение. Попробую так реализовать у себя, правда я это все делаю для Android с Java 7.

Comment: @Kostya там есть всякие AsyncTask и прочие примочки для того же

Comment: @Etki я знаю, но мне немножко AsyncTask не подходит для этой задачи.

Comment: @Kostya да, это просто единственное, что я знаю из асинхронщины в андроиде. Наверняка есть аналоги, если есть guava, то есть и ListenableFuture.